# Default Sort Order for Groups in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services

I cannot get the default sort order to work (on a date) in Report Builder when applied to a Group.  I can get interactive sorting to work, and I can get Tablix sorting to work on tables without groups.

I tried right-clicking on the table and then selecting "Tablix Properties" and then selecting Sorting and then using the expression CDate(Date).  (Date is the name of the group I want to sort by).  Interactive sorting works fine using that expression.

Comment: As the faq says it also includes: "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Comment: Why was this question closed, I use RS all the time and consider it programming related.  This site is getting very strange when it comes to even deciding where to ask a question.

Comment: Reporting Services is no longer considered software development? I agree with niktrs and JonH - closing this question is weird, and done by Jeff Atwood no less. Bizarre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Choose the detail row below the group at the bottom.
2. Right click and choose edit group properties.

   - [image: Row Groups]
3. Go to the sorting tab and add the date field without CDate

   - [image: Pick Sortin]

Comment: Thanks, I keep forgetting to look at the Row Groups at the bottom of the screen.  Actually I did need to use CDate though because otherwise the Dates were sorted in alphabetical order.  But otherwise it works!